# i tried to hide some tables in a div in a html page but doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, show-hide

i tried to hide some tables in a  div in a html page but doesn't work .
one of the html pages contains 10 tables.. i want to show only a few tables while selecting a particular department..currently i get the ids of those table need to show..but how to view those tables only..

tried jquery is attached here.. please help me .. i am in a stuck

```
    <script> 
               $(function() {
         $("#departments").change(function(v) {



               var gid=$(this).attr("id");
                  var department_id = v.target.value
                 //console.log(department_id);
                 $("#showData table").each(function(){
                //console.log($(this).attr("id"));

                var gid=$(this).attr("id");

            $('#'+gid).hide();

                $.get("/BankProfile/selectGroup/"+department_id+"/"+gid,function(data){
                        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                       // console.log(obj);
                  for(i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
                 var gid=obj[i].group_id;
                   console.log(gid);
                }
               });
               });
});
 });           
            </script>
```

Comment: Use ID selector `$('#'+gid)` and `.hide()/show()` methods.

Comment: i tried this .. but showing an error  ---- uncaught exception:syntax error,unrecognized expression:#

Comment: Have you included jQuery reference and is the syntax of your line correct? Show the error code.

Comment: How you have tried update it in code..

Comment: updated please check

Comment: What are the IDs for your tables??for example..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$("'" + "#" + gid + "'").hide();

Try this.

Comment: Write it and execute:

alert($(this).attr("id"));

What does it show?

Comment: thanks .. got it . the problem is using .operator in id

Answer (score 0):

use `.hide()` or `.show()` method or use display property if display is set to 'none' in JSP.

Comment: i tried this .. but showing an error ---- uncaught exception:syntax error,unrecognized expression:# –

Answer (score 0):

The ID of your tables are inappropriate for jquery selector. The periods(.) are used to identify the class of any element. So you have to change the naming conventions for your IDs.